# MongoDB / C# projection mis-understanding

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following:

```
var P = Builders<T>.Projection.Include(_ => _.AccountId);
var R = Mongo.Find(E).Project(P).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here's what I don't understand:

With that projection, I need T to include AccountId but also _id.
If I do not include _id, I get the following error:

```
{"Element '_id' does not match any field or property of class T."}
```

If I try to exclude _id, by doing the following:

```
var P = Builders<T>.Projection.Include(_ => _.AccountId).Exclude(_ => _._id);
var R = Mongo.Find(E).Project(P).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get a different error:

```
{"Element 'CreatedOn' does not match any field or property of class T."}
```

CreatedOn is another field from the record in the DB.

So, I'm afraid I don't understand how the projection really works:
I need to extract one field (AccountId) and nothing else (no _id), etc (and ideally map it to a string and not a class that contains just a string, but that's a secondary problem)

What am I missing?

Am I to understand that *Include* means take a blank slate, add all fields named in Include statements (and _id for some reason), while *Exclude* would mean 'take everything' and exclude specific fields?
In that case, these two commands would be exclusive.

Also, I can use:

```
Expression(_ => _.AccountId)
```

in my projection, and I get the result I want, but this doesn't clarify Include / Exclude

Comment: This is how I'll do in java. I dont have much knowledge of C# to convert it. `List<String> items = newColl.find().projection(fields(include("accountId"), excludeId())).map(item -> item.getString("accountId")).into(new ArrayList<>());`. May be you can figure it.

Comment: What I don’t understand is if the include directive means only what’s included and if the exclude means everything but what’s excluded and how they can work together; if include does bring up AccountId, we could assume that what is not included is not present; the opposite is true for the exclude directive, so using both together presents a conflict I don’t understand

Comment: Atleast Java mongo driver implementation takes care of conflicting projections by picking the last one in the order they are defined. I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: @Thomas I couldn't reproduce your problem. I have constructed similar situation and it works with include field, expclude id. What is your E in Find ? Could be, that you are using 'CreatedOn' there ?

Comment: Ultimately the problem is here, it's the inclusion of _id (the second problem in my post may stem from something else since the code base is complex with a bunch of generics): I get Format Exception {"Element '_id' does not match any field or property of class Test.T."} when doing: Driver.Find(_ => _.AccountId == "Test").Project<T>(Builders<DataObject>.Projection.Include(_ => _.AccountId)).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the document returned by the database contains a field, `CreatedOn`, which does not exist in the class of type `T`. You would need to add that field to the class `T` like so (assuming `CreatedOn` is a `DateTime`)

```
public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
```

Comment: but that defeats the goal of the projection: I want to return only specific fields, and CreatedOn is not one of them; I want specifically AccountId, but nothing else.

Comment: @Thomas can you post the definition of `T`?

Comment: T is a class with just AccountId and _id (as there is an error otherwise)